# Creating an object with a size to use with another class Java

Tags: java

Im using this:

```
public class DatabaseTester{
    public static void main (String[] args){

    final int length = 10;
    Database data = new Database(length);
...
}}
```

To set a size in this:

```
public class Database{

 private int length = _size;

    public Database(int length){
    int _size = length;
    }

    String[] list = new String[length];
...
}
```

But it is saying it cannot find _size and i have no idea why.

I need the array outside of public Database(){} to be used by other methods

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you must accept a value through a constructor, you need to move the initialization of your array into the constructor as well, like this:

```
String[] list;
public Database(int length) {
    int _size = length;
    list = new String[length];
}
```

This is because the scope of constructor parameters is limited to the constructor itself - you cannot use them in initializers. You cannot use `_size` either, because it would be set to zero at the time the initializer runs.

Note that you can get rid of `_size`, because you can always get it by accessing `list.length`:

```
public class Database {
    String[] list;
    public Database(int length){
        list = new String[length];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i updated my post on why i need the array outside the constructor. And this did work so thank you, i did the same thing you did with length as well, i forgot i couldn't declare it inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find `_size` because that variable is not defined within the scope of your class.

```
public class Database{

 private int length = _size;

    public Database(int length){
      // this is a local variable, so even if you have this here
      // it is not something the Database class will know about
      int _size = length;
    }

    String[] list = new String[length];
...
}
```

If you would like your array to be a public field you can do this

```
public class Database {

    String[] list;

    public Database(int length){
       list =  = new String[length];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems wrong and redundant:

```
public class Database {
  private int length;
  private String[] list;

  public Database(int length) {
    this.length = length;
    this.list = new String[length];
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i updated my post on why i need the array outside the constructor.

Comment: The declaration of `list` is still outside the constructor, you can refer to it in any other method of `Database`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the constructor is used to init 
You should code the DataBase class in this way. the instance variables.

```
public class Database{

    private int length;
    String[] list;

    public Database(int length){
       this.length = length;
       this.list = new String(length);
    }


...
}
```